# SQL INSERT Calculate NoOfDays Between A Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
    CREATE TABLE "Reservation"(

    ReservationID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID int NOT NULL,
    RoomNo int NOT NULL,
    CheckInDate date NULL,
    CheckOutDate date NULL,
    NoOfDays int NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Reservation PRIMARY KEY(ReservationID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Customers_CustID FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)  
        REFERENCES dbo.Customers(CustomerID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Rooms_RoomNo FOREIGN KEY(RoomNo)
        REFERENCES dbo.Rooms(RoomNo)
)


INSERT Reservation(CustomerID,RoomNo,CheckInDate,CheckOutDate,NoOfDays)
        VALUES(1,101,'2012-01-01','2012-01-30',DATEDIFF(NoOfDays,'CheckInDate','CheckOutDate'))
```

Can someone please tell me how i can calculate the number of days between "CheckInDate" and "CheckOutDate" then have this value in the insert statement for NoOfDays. It's hard to explain i hope you understood what i'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: The number of days is derived information, something you're not usually supposed to store - especially in light of the fact that you're _already_ storing checkin/out information. Don't name columns with type information, name them by use:  `CheckInDate` should probably be `checkingInOn`, `arrivingOn`, etc.  `CheckOutDate` should probably be something like `checkingOutBy`, `departingBefore`, etc (and would probably be best as an 'exclusive' upper bound).  Alternatively, ditch the checking out date, and store `stayDuration` (in integer days or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED:

Try this:

```
INSERT Reservation(CustomerID,RoomNo,CheckInDate,CheckOutDate,NoOfDays)
    VALUES(1,101,'2012-01-01','2012-01-30',DATEDIFF(day,'2012-01-01','2012-01-30'));
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0eb58/1)

Comment: Hi it works, but is it not possible to automatically generate the noofdays based on the specified columns (checkindate, checkoutdate)? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @user1638362 - Check the fiddle, that shows the modified query.  Although, András, you should probably include statement here, for completeness.

Comment: @user1638362 : After an insert you can update it. Or an INSERT trigger could be that option. But not in the INSERT statement.